# Create Button Dynamically in WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a window creator class for WINAPI..

I'm stuck figuring out how to get the Window to add controls dynamically and register message for them.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class WinForm
{
    private:
        HWND WindowHandle = nullptr;
        std::thread Thread;
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>> ControlHandles;

    public:
        ~WinForm();
        WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded = false, int Width = CW_USEDEFAULT, int Height = CW_USEDEFAULT, WNDPROC WindowProcedure = nullptr, WNDCLASSEX WndClass = {0});
        bool AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height);
};

WinForm::~WinForm()
{
    if (Thread.joinable())
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
}

WinForm::WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded, int Width, int Height, WNDPROC WindowProcedure, WNDCLASSEX WndClass)
{
    if (WindowProcedure == nullptr)
    {
        WindowProcedure = [](HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT __stdcall
        {
            switch(msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT:
                break;

                case WM_DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;

                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }

    if (WndClass.cbSize == 0)
    {
        WndClass =
        {
            sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
            0, 0, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION),
            LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
            nullptr, ClassName.c_str(), LoadIcon (nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION)
        };
    }

    if (RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        if (Threaded)
        {
            Thread = std::thread([ClassName, WindowName, Width, Height, this]{
                WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
                if(WindowHandle)
                {
                    MSG msg = {nullptr};
                    ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
                    while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
                    {
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
            if(WindowHandle)
            {
                MSG msg = {nullptr};
                ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
                while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool WinForm::AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height)
{
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (ButtonName == std::get<0>(*it))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::size_t ID = 1;
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it, ++ID)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) != ID)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    HWND ButtonHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, "Button", ButtonName.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, Location.x, Location.y, Width, Height, WindowHandle, (HMENU)ID, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
    ControlHandles.push_back(std::make_tuple(ButtonName, ID, ButtonHandle));
    SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CREATE, 0, 0);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    WinForm Form("Class", "Title", true);
    Form.AddButton("NewButton", {50, 50}, 25, 25);
}
```

In the above, it compiles fine and shows the Window just fine.. It just does not show the button which I tried to add dynamically to the window. Does anyone have any idea how I can dynamically add buttons to the window and allow the button to register messages?

Comment: It's unlikely that it's the cause of your problem, but I see no reason to send a `WM_CREATE` message after a button is created.

Comment: @chris Not only is there no reason, it is explicitly disallowed. `WM_CREATE` is sent by the system as part of creation. If you send it manually, then you're [prank-calling the window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/26/10216420.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen, I was somewhat aware of that for `WM_DESTROY`, but not `WM_CREATE`. I also think I've somehow not read that one before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of issues, but the main one is the WM_PAINT handler you have. This will prevent the main window to paint this children Window. Comment it out (and solve other issue), and you'll be fine.

1. Threaded - not sure whether this is an issue or not. This is completely not standard. Create the main Window on the main thread (EDIT: I believe the problem with threaded is that your create the main window - and have the message loop on one thread, while the control window is in a different thread. This is not allowed).
2. Your logic when `Threaded` is false is wrong. You can't have the message loop there. The constructor of WinForm should return. Otherwise, you'll never get to the Form.AddButton.
3. Do the message loop as the last thing Within main
4. I think you aren't using Visual Studio. There are many syntax issues (c++11 stuff Microsoft not yet implement), and the main function for Windows application is named WinMain. That's fine, but not recommended. Microsoft has an excellent free compiler, and if you used the paid compiler you could use ATL which is awesome.
5. Without commenting out WM_PAINT, your button is created, but it isn't visible. You could spot it with Spy++
6. Remove the `case WM_PAIN:`. You are blocking the DefWindowProc which will call the sub window to point themselves.
7. First time I see lambda notation for Widnow Proc. This is a nice trick, but I really see no reason for.

Code below is working, and contains fixes for visual Studio 2012. Note that Microsoft doesn't have initialization list yet (which is a bummer). You are welcome.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

WNDCLASSEX defWndClass = { 0 };

class WinForm
{
    private:
        HWND WindowHandle;
        std::thread Thread;
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>> ControlHandles;

    public:
        ~WinForm();
        WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded = false, int Width = CW_USEDEFAULT,
            int Height = CW_USEDEFAULT, WNDPROC WindowProcedure = nullptr, WNDCLASSEX WndClass = defWndClass);
        bool AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height);
};

WinForm::~WinForm()
{
    if (Thread.joinable())
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
}

WinForm::WinForm(std::string ClassName, std::string WindowName, bool Threaded, int Width, int Height, WNDPROC WindowProcedure, WNDCLASSEX WndClass)
    :WindowHandle(nullptr)
{
    if (WindowProcedure == nullptr)
    {
        WindowProcedure = [](HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT __stdcall
        {
            switch(msg)
            {
                /*
                case WM_PAINT:
                    break;
                    */

                case WM_DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;

                case WM_CREATE:
                    break;

                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
            }
            return 0;
        };
    }

    if (WndClass.cbSize == 0)
    {
        WndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
        WndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = ClassName.c_str();
        WndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon( nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    }

    if (RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        if (Threaded)
        {
            // can't do that!
        }
        else
        {
            WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), WindowName.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
            if(WindowHandle)
            {
                ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

                // don't put message loop here!
            }
        }
    }
}

bool WinForm::AddButton(std::string ButtonName, POINT Location, int Width, int Height)
{
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it)
    {
        auto& tu = *it;
        auto& str = std::get<0>(tu);
        if( ButtonName.compare( str ) == 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    std::size_t ID = 1;
    for (std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::size_t, HWND>>::iterator it = ControlHandles.begin(); it != ControlHandles.end(); ++it, ++ID)
    {
        if (std::get<1>(*it) != ID)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    HWND ButtonHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        0, "button", ButtonName.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, Location.x, Location.y, Width, Height, 
        WindowHandle, (HMENU)ID, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
    ShowWindow( ButtonHandle, SW_SHOW );
    ControlHandles.push_back(std::make_tuple(ButtonName, ID, ButtonHandle));

    //SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_CREATE, 0, 0);
    return true;
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int )
{
    WinForm Form("Class", "Title", false);
    POINT pt = { 50, 50 };
    Form.AddButton("NewButton", pt, 80, 50);

    MSG msg = {nullptr};
    while(GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ohh I used the lambda because I wasn't able to use the callback within the class unless it was static and I didn't want a static call back as I needed each callback to be different for every instance of the class. I had added the threading because of the blocking which you are right. Removing the loop fixed it.

I used int main because it was a console application I was using and the class was to spawn multiple windows :) Thank you!! For taking the time to help me.

Comment: lambda - Well, let me know if I'm missing something. With the current state of the code - it is the same callback for every instance. Moreover, you don't have a state in the callback, since the closure is empty. I believe you will not be able to put anything in the closure - because if you had a non-trivial closure, the assignment to the Windows Proc will not succeed. WNDPROC indeed doesn't have context (other than HWND), and as such must be static. The standard way to solve it is with SetWindowLong, or somethign similar to ATL's thunks. Let me know if you have something better.